# Images like a progress bar based on table value?

Tags: php

I'd like to create a progress bar with few images. Let me explain. Currently, it's displaying like this on the website: `Online users: 50` (EXAMPLE)
However, I want to replace the text with a similiar progress bar to total of 5 images for example. Let me explain. First image is the progress bar with one line (for 25 users online) if it hits more than 25 to show the second image with two lines and etc. I hope you understand me, and will be greatly appreciated to help me out. I will make the images myself but howerver, I am not sure how the progress bar should be. It's not required to be AJAX,Javascript or anything like that. Just simple progress bar with 4-5 images and they should be changing upon getting getloggedincount value ...

This below is the function: (it's writing/reading the value from a text file, so I can cache the result for 5 minutes.)

```
    function GetLoggedInCount()
    {
        $cachefile = './cachefiles/count.txt';
        $db = $this->database[ADB];         
        if (!file_exists($cachefile) || (time() - 300) >= filemtime($cachefile))
        {
            $count = 0;
            $num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT COUNT(AccountID) as pCount FROM ONLINEUSERS');
            if ($num_rows == 1)
            {
                $row = $db->doRead();
                $count = $row['pCount'];
                $fp = fopen($cachefile, 'w');
                fwrite($fp, $count);
                fclose($fp);
            }
            return $count;
        }
        else if ((time() - 300) < filemtime($cachefile))
        {
            $fp = fopen($cachefile, 'r');
            $content = fread($fp, filesize($cachefile));
            fclose($fp);
            return intval($content);
        }
    }

        Template::SetVar('pcount', $this->GetLoggedInCount());
```

........

Comment: pls share your markup.

Comment: Actually, I found a way. Just wanna know the following: `Template::SetVar('pcount', $this->GetLoggedInCount() < 50 ? IMAGE1 : IMAGE2);` How to include more checks and so display different images? This current will display IMAGE1 if players are less than 50 otherwise it will display image2, but how to add additional on that if less than 100 display image3 and etc, i hope you understand me?

Comment: you can use a `switch` statement

Comment: How I can use the switch statement in this : `Template::SetVar('pcount', $this->GetLoggedInCount() < 50 ? IMAGE1 : IMAGE2);` ?

Comment: I am learning at this moment. Nobody said that I am pro. I am still a newbie and that's why I am asking here. Sorry if I am offending you but please keep these statements for yourself.

Comment: you're not offending me. I tried to render my most sincere _help_ for you. You do not need to be a pro to know the switch statement. It is pretty basic. It is the 2nd thing (1st is if statement) you probably learn in "conditional statements" chapter of your "Intro. to programming" book.

Comment: I do know to use `switch` statements in normal structure, however, I am struggling to do it in this template structure as mentioned above. I am sorry once again but that's why I am here to learn more during my tests. If it doesn't offend you and you're willing to help me out. Can you just show me a basic structure how it should look like in my example: `Template::SetVar('pcount', $this->GetLoggedInCount() < 50 ? IMAGE1 : IMAGE2);` this will be so much appreciated and I will be able to fully understand how it should work. Thanks once again!

Comment: Are they different images, or just one? Basically, if I understand correctly, you just want to show X images, where X is (LoggedInCount / 25) is that right?

Comment: Exactly. I've got 5 images which have different (progress bar looking like) progress. So, 1st image less than 50 online, 2nd image 50 online above and less than 100 and etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this.

```
/**
 * Returns overall count of users in your system
 * 
 * @todo You need to write this function!
 * @return int 
 */
function GetOverallUsers(){} 

/**
 * Returns amount of logged in users
 * @return int
 */
function GetLoggedInCount(){}

//How many images do you have?
$numberOfDifferentPictures = 5;

$pictureNumber = ceil(GetLoggedInCount() / GetOverallUsers() * $numberOfDifferentPictures);

Template::SetVar('imageNumber', $pictureNumber);
```

Somewhere in your template

```
<img src="image{{imageNumber}}.png"/>
```

I think this will work for you, but it would be ways better if you can move this evaluation in your template and pass only amount of logged and overall users to templating engine.

---

And BTW, I think you should look at some CSS progress bars. They are really simple and fancy and you don't need to mess with pictures. Just small HTML+CSS snippet and you're ready to go.